# Is it possible to export Windows event logs from multiple servers to a non-windows host, without running event manager on each of the Windows servers?

Tags: windows, unix, windows-event-log

I want to export event logs from Windows to a non-Windows host. I was considering using Logstash, but that would seem to require that I install and run Logstash on each server. Is it possible to do this without having to run it on all of the servers?

I am hoping to be able to consolidate all of the information from different servers to make searching and reporting much easier.

If not, what would you recommend is the best way to export to a non-Windows host in real time?

Comment: Well,one way of doing it could be ... The event logs on the Windows servers are stored in a certain folder. ( C:\windows\system32\config with .evt extension in Windows server 2003). You could share this folder on the windows boxes and have them exported on the non-windows box. You could use a script to copy from multiple servers to one location....

Comment: You then can also export those logs to a .txt or .csv format and then have them exported via Robocopy or a powershell script

Comment: @ServerFaulter if those logs have open handles to them (which they all should) you'll probably get corrupt copies. Have you actually verified that a straight copy from a shared folder works?

Comment: @MDMarra, Probably...I haven't had the chance to verify...However, I could save the logs separately and not have them as current for reporting to avoid any possibilities of corrupt data.

Answer (score 3):

So presuming that all your servers are Windows 2008 R2 or higher, you can use [Event Log Forwarding](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890.aspx) to forward all the Event Logs to a central server, then use Logstach (or whatever - I like Splunk myself if you have less than 500MB of logs/day) to just grab that logs off of that one central server.

Comment: I think that you mean megabytes.

Comment: Ah, good point, yep.  I've edited to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an Eventlog-to-Syslog exporter such as [this](http://code.google.com/p/eventlog-to-syslog/) and enable remote logging on the central loghost. This, for example, is enabled in modern distributions that use `rsyslog` in /etc/rsyslog.conf via

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

From there, the options to manage your logs are endless: graylog2/logstash, splunk, php-syslog-ng or a number of other solutions (google is your friend!)